# deleting migration, any problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a migration, `add_content_to_users content:string`. I ran `db:migrate` and in the `edit` page I added text into this `content` attribute. I realized I wanted to do something else, so I want to get rid of `content.` Is `db:rollback` sufficient, or do I have to also reset and migrate the database again (would rather not) using something like `db:migrate:reset`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rake db:rollback` undoes the last migration (in most cases) if it added a column, it will drop said column completely from your database table.  All data in the column is lost.

If you don't alter or remove that migration file of course, the column will be added again the next time you run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: right that makes sense. so I don't need to do `db:migrate:reset`?

Comment: `db:reset` I believe is the command you are referring to, which not only runs all your migrations but your seeding as well, and no I don't believe based on your questions you need to run it.  Rollback the migration, delete (or alter) the file and you should be ok.